# SqlException breakConnection

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this SqlException when I am trying to Insert data into the database. Any help with this error would be great.

c# Code

```cs
UnitOfWork.GetRepository<StyleGuideNote>().Insert(newVersion);
   
if (status != null)
{
    ArchivePreviousPublishedVersion(newVersion);
}
UnitOfWork.Save();
```

```
Unhandled Exception (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out

       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicUpdate(TrackedObject item)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at OrderTemplateTool.Data.OrderTemplateDataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) in C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Data\OrderTemplateDataContext.cs:line 143
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
       at OrderTemplateTool.Repository.Common.UnitOfWork.Save() in C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Repository\Common\UnitOfWork.cs:line 82
```

Comment: Is there a message with the exception?

Comment: What's the actual exception message? The stack trace only tells us where it's thrown from.

Comment: Its a Execution Timeout Expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
> server is not responding. The statement has been terminated.

Is a client-side timeout occuring during your Linq2SQL `DataContext.SubmitChanges()`.  Unless your [CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8) is set very short, it's likely caused by blocking on the server, but server-side monitoring is needed to diagnose.  Try turning on [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15), and monitoring the [Session Wait Stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the session attempting the insert.

Comment: I did check for a deadlock and there wasn’t one or is this something different?

Comment: A deadlock will raise an error and rollback on one of the sessions to break the deadlock.  This is something different.